# Sudden problems when trying to decrypt a file using openssl

Tags: openssl

For a number of years I've been placing text that I want to encrypt into a file called "Plain.txt" and then running:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in Plain.txt -out Encrypted.bin
```

which have produced a file called Encrypted.bin. To then decrypt this file and get the contents of the original text file back, I've been running:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in Encrypted.bin
```

and then simply type in my password. This has so far worked without any problem.

Today, when trying to do this, I received the following output from my terminal:

```
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
4529569280:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad      decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
?9?C?xm?A"???ր~?G?P?dj??.???N?m ?
```

This has occurred across devices (both on MacOS and Raspberry Pi OS) and across different sources of my backed up, encrypted files. I don't understand what's going on at all. I can't get my original content, and I've never seen these kind of errors and output before.

Comment: Did you encrypt with an openssl version below 1.1.0? (You must have if you encrypted files before 2016, and maybe even somewhat after, because that's when 1.1.0 was released upstream, and many people, systems, or distros didn't switch to it immediately.)  1.1.0 and up changed the default hash in the key derivation, and the warning you show confirms you are using 1.1.1 to (try to) decrypt. See 'Inter-version compatibility' in (my) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614

Answer (score 2):

Default key enforcement mechanism has change between openssl versions (md5 vs sha256).

```
# openssl-1.1.1
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in Plain.txt -out Encrypted.bin  -p -pass pass:test -nosalt
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
key=9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
iv =206DFC4E0335FA0AD986B9C1942DD653

# openssl-1.0.2
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in Plain.txt -out Encrypted.bin  -p -pass pass:test -nosalt
key=098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F60A9172716AE6428409885B8B829CCB05
iv =C9DD4BB33B827EB1FBA1B16A0074D460
```

as you see keys are not equals and decypher fails

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in Encrypted.bin  -p -pass pass:test -nosalt
key=098F6BCD4621D373CADE4E832627B4F60A9172716AE6428409885B8B829CCB05
iv =C9DD4BB33B827EB1FBA1B16A0074D460
bad decrypt
6736:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:.\crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:563
```

To decypher the `Encrypted.bin` file with openssl-1.0.2 use the flag `-md sha256`

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in Encrypted.bin  -p -pass pass:test -md sha256 -nosalt
key=9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08
iv =206DFC4E0335FA0AD986B9C1942DD653
Hello
```

PS: I used the flag `-nopad` for the purpose of the demonstration